# How to test node.js module which returns anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, express

I'm writing small middleware for express.js route, but when I came to unit test this code I stuck, and I don't know how to properly test it using mocha, sinon and chai.

My middleware code has entrypoint something like this:

```
 const searchByQuerystring = require('./search-by-querystring');
 const searchByMarker = require('./search-by-marker');

 module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

   if (req.marker) {
      searchByMarker(req, res, next);
   } else if (req.query) {
      searchByQuerystring(req, res, next);
   } else {
      next();
   }
};
```

, and during unit test I would like to test if method **searchByMarker** or **searchByQuerystring** was called.

So I start with writing this test,

```
it('Should call search by querystring if querystring is present', () => {
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
            query: {
                value: 1000
            }
        }),
        res = httpMocks.createResponse(),
        next = sandbox.spy();
    searchIndex(req, res, next);

    sinon.assert.calledOnce(next);
});
```

where my middleware should use **searchByQuerystring** for process request and I would like to test it if **searchByQuerystring** method was called, but I really don't know how to do that, maybe i just should write this code in some other way, I really don't want to use libraries like [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire) .

Maybe my module is doing too much work (according to Single Responsibility Principle) - but whole middleware is for build search object where on start I just need to find out from which place parameters will came, so I thought that it is a good idea to put this logic on start of the middleware - and I just should have two middlewares?

Please for any help, suggestions about this.

Comment: Unless the functions you're trying to test are accessible in one way or another or you can verify which function was called based on output, your best bet is probably to instead rely on a code coverage tool like [`istanbul`](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul).

Comment: Thank you @mscdex for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright,

So putting this post help me to to find a solution. I rewrite my middleware entry point, to looking like this

```
const searchRequestParser = require('./search-request-parser');
const search = require('../../../lib/search');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {

  const searchRequest = searchRequestParser(req);
  if (searchRequest) {
    const searchCriteria = search(searchRequest.resourceToSearch);
    req.searchQuery = 
  searchCriteria.buildQuery(searchRequest.queryParameters);
  }
  next();
};
```

And test

```
    it('Should call search by querystring if querystring is present', () => {
    const req = httpMocks.createRequest({
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                resourceToSearch: 'debts'
            },
            query: {
                value: 1000
            }
        }),
        res = httpMocks.createResponse(),
        next = sandbox.spy();
    searchIndex(req, res, next);

    expect(req).to.have.a.property('searchQuery');
});
```

So methods **searchByMarker** or **searchByQuerystring** are gone and replaced by method **searchRequestParser** with output, then I process this output in code which as it turned out was duplicated previously in methods **searchByMarker** or **searchByQuerystring**.

Thanks to return outputs from functions I used, I didn't have to focus on mocking/stubing those functions.